# OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found when using IClassFixture

Tags: c#, testing, integration, xunit

I'm trying to follow this example found here, [example](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-6-supporting-integration-tests-with-webapplicationfactory-in-dotnet-6/).

I'm always hit with this error,
Message: OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found

```
namespace ***.Application.IntegrationTests.ControllerTests;
public class AppCodeControllerTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{

private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

public AppCodeControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
{

    _factory = factory;
}
```

Any tips, is there something I'm missing. xunit ver 2.4.2 & NET 6 btw. Why is it not seeing the constructor?

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not an image. Also, what version of xunit are you using?

Comment: The message is from NUnit. Seems you've missed XUnit/NUnit. The example for XUnit.